# how to measure the fluctuation of data used for fitting a curve?

Tags: matlab, regression, interpolation, system-identification

Given a series of data points that are used to fit a smooth curve, how to measure the fluctuation of the data?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mean how you measure the accuracy of the fitted model? One of the basic measure is the MSE which measures the empirical mean squared error of the prediction. I.e., let $\hat{y}(x_i)$ be the fitted value for the $x_i$-th data point and $y_i$ its actual $y$ value, hence the MSE is defined as 
$$
MSE(\text{model}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{y}_i - y_i)^2\, .
$$
Note that the more you "smooth" your data, the lower the computed MSE. This does not necessarily mean that you got the best model as too smooth model will be an over-fitting and hence your model will probably predict poorly out of sample data.

Comment: Thanks, on the occasion that the true model is unknown, but the model is assumed to be smooth. need to find a function that describes the fluctuation of the data points used to approximate the underlying transformation.

Comment: Have you tried to estimate $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1\sin(x_i) +\epsilon_i$?

Comment: any more details?

Comment: It seems that your data follows the pattern of sinus, hence the basic model that you can fit is the aforementioned one. If you won't be satisfied with the fit, then you can cal calibrate the model. Otherwise, if you are not interested in model at all, you can fit polynomials, or LOWESS etc.